# .net core to endpoint API System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I have a problem with an HTTP request initiated from a C# program hosted on a raspberry Pi connected to the internet with a 4G box.
The HTTP requests are sent to a NodeJS API deployed by docker and accessible through a reverse proxy.
Several requests are sent at regular intervals, however the following error ends the program after several exchanges:

```
 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at Common.WebApi.SendHttpPost(String url, StringContent data)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_1(Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.<>c.<.cctor>b__5_0(Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.ExecuteWorkItem()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Resource temp
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at Common.WebApi.SendHttpPost(String url, StringContent data)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_1(Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.<>c.<.cctor>b__5_0(Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.ExecuteWorkItem()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at Common.WebApi.SendHttpPost(String url, StringContent data)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_1(Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.<>c.<.cctor>b__5_0(Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.ExecuteWorkItem()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
sept. 21 15:25:15 raspberrypi [15749]:    at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

This error occurs at any time and I can't catch it